# Can git produce a list of the authors who originally wrote the code modified by a patch?

Tags: git

For instance, say I write a patch and the lines that change were originally written by `Errol Ryehouse`, `Augustus Parsons`, and `Flint Chittles`.

When I go to submit this patch to an unfamiliar project, I'd like to know who to ask for a review. Is there a way to produce a list of these names automatically, without having to go through and `blame` each changed file individually?

Ideally I'd want to use this on a range of patches, like `origin/master..HEAD`.

Is this possible?

Comment: That looks really nice! Having the blame inline with the diff is especially useful.

Comment: I removed the comment because I realized that it's not _exactly_ want you want.... anyway, here's the URL: https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame

Comment: With a bit more scripting, the names could be easily extracted, sorted, and uniquified, but it's nice to have the extra context of the diff so I probably won't bother :)

Answer (score 0):

You can list the author of commits to individual files by providing a path.

```
git log --follow --pretty="%h %cn" -Lm,n origin/master..HEAD -- PATH/TO/FILE
```

`--follow` detects file renames.
`--pretty="%h %cn"` prints commit hash and author
`-Lm,n` specify line numbers m=min, n=max

Comment: That's pretty close, but some of these files are 10k lines long and 25 years old, so lots of authors working on different parts.  It'd be nice to get something that's last-change-per-line.

Comment: Added line number argument

Comment: You could even auto-generate the `-L` args from the hunk headers in your own commit.